# Handler not working in Android

Tags: android

I' trying to increment a value in TextView when button was clicked and used Handler as below. Its not incrementing the value of i and displaying only 1 after button was clicked

My activity code is as below

```
public void changeTxt(View view) {

        // invoke handler and call the thread method for every one second

        threadHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                i = i + 1;
                txtVw.setText(" Number :: " + i);
            }
        }, 0);

    }
```

Related button layout is

```
 <Button android:id="@+id/buttn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Add Value" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtView"
       android:onClick="changeTxt"

       />
```

Comment: No errors, no bugs, no logcat

Comment: It's not showing any errors..

Comment: Where did you define `i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // invoke handler and call the thread method for every one second

Your code isn't doing that. Try

```
threadHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Whatevs
            threadHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks . It worked. So if we write directly postDelayed and not within post method, it doesn't work. Am i correct?

Comment: Given that your first call has no delay, it's better to use the correct API. And yes, it keeps calling itself because postDelay doesn't loop.

Answer (score 0):

> private int i = 0; 
>   must be global

Maybe you forgot to initialize Handler. Сhecked the code myself and it works.

```
 threadHandler = new Handler();
 buttn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 txtVw = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```